# Figure out number of commands from assembly form

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

I have a C file and i converted it into assembly form and i'd like to figure out how many instructions are on the main function using gdb and the assembly file. How can i do that?

Comment: Please post more detail in the question, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I think i meant "instructions", my terminology is not that good. Point is, the exercise I'm doing says that I'm supposed to use the "x/??i *main" command and then figure put how many instructions are on main

Comment: Still no clearer than mud. Please ask a proper question.

Comment: Without a concrete example this question can't really be answered. Also what do you mean by "how many instructions"? As in how many execute during operation, or how many are in the code? An optimizing compiler might unroll loops for speed even if it seems like "more instructions".

Comment: compile then disassemble and count manually.  understand that different compilers or different versions of the same compiler as well as compiler settings/options can/will give vastly different results while still providing functionally correct code.  (and as tadman pointed out are you asking about total number or a particular execution path or what?)

Comment: @tadman: With the comment and edit, it is clear.

Comment: also understand that while assembly language tries to be one to one, it is not, in particular compilers generate a lot of extra directives and other communication with the assembler.  In gdb though this should be more of a disassembly than the compiled to assembly so that is a lot cleaner.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It's still vague to me, but I guess you've got a handle on it.

Answer (score 1):

In the debugger, type `x/10i main`. That shows the first ten instructions after the `main` entry point. (You can use a number other than ten, as you prefer.) Look for a return instruction. It may be something like `ret` or `retq`. If it does not appear in the first ten instructions, press return. (This repeats/continues the previous command, showing the next ten instructions. You an also type `x/10i` to continue from the current location.) When you see the return instruction, count the instructions from `main` to it.

You can also compile to assembly with GCC’s `-S` switch. This will produce a file containing assembly source, name `foo.s` if your source file was named `foo.c`. Then you can look at it in a text editor to count instructions from the `main:` label to the return. (This file may be cluttered with various other information—labels with no instructions, comments inserts by the compiler for information/debugging purposes, special assembler directives that are not instructions, and so on, so counting instructions in it may be difficult if you are unfamiliar with which things are instructions and which are not. The debugger may be easier to use for this task since it shows raw instructions.)

Technically, a function in C does not necessarily compile to a simple set of sequential instructions. The compiler may embed code from called functions into the calling function. It could, in theory, put the instructions for one function in multiple different places (although compilers tend not to do this, in my experience), with jumps between them. So counting instructions is not generally useful for more than simple classroom exercises and learning explorations.

Comment: I dont think x86 was specified...good chance that it is though.

Comment: @old_timer: Hence the “it may be something like…”